# How to find maximum value from a tuple list in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, for-loop

I have a code with all this so far:

```
import math

nList = [[[0,0,0],[3,2,1]],\
[[]],\
[[1,1,12]],\
[[0,0,0],[30000,40,3010],[32000,40500,7520],[0,0,10520]],\
[[15340,0,0],[104300,0,3630], [434000,4434000,63460],[400340, 404300, 9430],[10340,0,1334320]]]



MaxLengthPerTrace=[[]]

traceCount = len(nList)
prevX = 0
prevY = 0
prevT = 0
maxLengthTempList=0

def calculateLength(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return math.sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2)
def calculateTime (t1,t2):
    return abs(t1-t2)

#Entry point
for traceIndex in range(0, len(nList)):
    print 'trace: ' + str(traceIndex+1)

    trace = nList[traceIndex]
    for pointIndex in range(0, len(trace)):
        point = trace[pointIndex]

        if len(point)>0:
            tempX = point[0]
            tempY = point[1]
            tempT = point[2]

            if pointIndex != 0:

                #Calulate Length here
                length = calculateLength(tempX, tempY, prevX, prevY)
                print length


                #Calculate Maximum Length here
```

How would I write a program to calculate a maximum length from length? I wrote pseudo-code for this as

```
        if(length > max)
            max = length;   

        add the length in MaxLengthPerTrace in index of traceindex
```

but can't seem to execute it in Python 2.7.10 properly. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

I tried this but it didn't work, coming with error: "for i in length:
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable"

```
for i in length:
                if i >length:
                    i=length
                    MaxLengthPerTrace.append(i)
                    print MaxLengthPerTrace
```

Comment: Max would be the maximum length from the lengths identified within function:  length => def calculateLength(x1, y1, x2, y2):  return math.sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2)  ...  calculateLength(tempX, tempY, prevX, prevY)

Comment: How do you represent a point in the space? With only two coordinate or with three coordinate?

Comment: A point is three coordinates so [0,0,0] in 1st one for example.

Comment: As a quick note, you don't need to use `\\` for line continuation inside list literals - the brackets imply line continuation until they are closed in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to have a couple of issues, so I'm going to have to make a few guesses, but hopefully this helps.

This is a good case for a [generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python). You have an iterable (the traces), and want to do something reasonably complicated to create a new iterable (the lengths):

```
nList = [[[0, 0, 0], [3, 2, 1]],
         [[]],
         [[1, 1, 12]],
         [[0, 0, 0], [30000, 40, 3010], [32000, 40500, 7520], [0, 0, 10520]],
         [[15340, 0, 0], [104300, 0, 3630], [434000, 4434000, 63460],
          [400340, 404300, 9430], [10340, 0, 1334320]]]

def calculate_length(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return math.sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2)

def calculate_time (t1,t2):
    return abs(t1-t2)

def lengths(traces):
    previous_x, previous_y = 0, 0
    for trace in traces:
        for index, point in enumerate(trace):
            if point:
                x, y, t = point
                if index > 0:
                    yield calculate_length(x, y, previous_x, previous_y)
                previous_x, previous_y = x, y  # Was this intended?

print(max(lengths(nList)))
```

In your code, you never set `prevX` and `prevY`, which I assume is a bug. I've given a guess at what you want here.

Note the changes I have made - firstly, iterating by index in Python is slow, unreadable, and generally never a good idea - Python `for` loops iterate directly over iterables, no need to count. If you need the index (as in the second case to check if it's not the first value), we can use `enumerate()` to get that as well.

Once we have an iterable of the lengths, it's trivial to obtain the maximal length using the `max()` built-in.

If you wanted the maximum length per-trace, rather than over the entire data set, you can simple change the level the function works at (remove the outermost loop and change the input argument to `trace`), and then call it inside a [list comprehension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw), for example:

```
def lengths(trace):
    previous_x, previous_y = 0, 0
    for index, point in enumerate(trace):
        if point:
            x, y, t = point
            if index > 0:
                yield calculate_length(x, y, previous_x, previous_y)
            previous_x, previous_y = x, y

print([max(lengths(trace)) for trace in nList])
```

As a final note, I also changed the code style to match [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) - this is not vital, but it helps make your code consistent with most examples you will find and makes it easier to recognise things at a glance. Mostly this just means I've renamed variables.

Comment: I set prevX and prevY to 0 towards the top part.

Comment: @sayna Indeed, I didn't word that well - what I mean is they are always `0`, which I assumed wasn't intended as the names implied they were meant to be the previous point (which would explain their involvement in calculating a length - from point to point), if that's not the intention, you'll need to explain what you are looking for.

Comment: you got it spot on. New to programming so building up one block at a time!

Comment: @sayna Great. I may have introduced a lot of concepts in my post, but hopefully you can see that they make the code much easier to understand once you know about those language features. If you break down my post and look at the parts, it should really help you write more Pythonic code (which should mean it's easier to work with for you).

Comment: Hi @Lattywire, thanks for all the help. When I try to find max length per trace: def length(traces):
    previous_x, previous_y = 0, 0
    for trace in traces:
        for index, point in enumerate(trace):
                if point:
                    x, y, t = point
                    if index > 0:
                        yield calculate_length(x, y, previous_x, previous_y)
##                  previous_x, previous_y = x, y  # Was this intended?

print([max(length(trace)) for trace in nList])
                 I get an error saying "x, y, t = point
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

Comment: @sayna Are you passing in `nList` or an element *from* `nList`? The error implies that it's iterating down too many levels and trying to make a point from a number inside a point. If you want to get the maximum per-trace, you will need to remove the outermost loop and change the method argument to `trace` as I mentioned.

Comment: I know this is a very nooby question but which outer oop do i remove?

Comment: @sayna I edited the answer to show the example. The outer loop just means the first one in the function.

Comment: Hi Lattywire, thanks again but if I try to run it, it is giving the error: "ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence"

Comment: @sayna That means you are not getting any results from your generator. This will be because of your second value where the are no points. You can stop it by adding a guard to your list comprehension, to exclude traces with no lines. e.g: `print([max(lengths(trace)) for trace in nList if len(trace) > 1])`. When you come across errors like this, try printing out the individual parts of the program - see where the values you get don't match with what you get, and try to work out why.

Comment: Hi again @Lattyware. Is there a way to store the results of yield calculate_length(x, y, previous_x, previous_y) in a list?

Comment: @sayna A generator is just a type of iterable, so to make it a list you can use the `list()` built-in function, as with any iterable. i.e.: `list(lengths(values))`.

Comment: Hi @Lattyware. Could you please tell me how to print the output of all the lengths as well, not just the maximum?

Comment: @sayna If you have a list of the lengths (as above), you can loop over it and print the values, and then get the maximum of it with `max()`. If you have more questions, please post them as actual questions rather than comments on this answer.

Comment: Thanks @Lattyware. I did. Appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 2):

I changed your code a little bit **just to clear the point where you get stuck**. But this way of writing program is **very unclear**. I strongly recommend to enhance functional solutions of other folks here instead of improving your C-like style code.

```
import math

nList = [[[0,0,0],[3,2,1]],\
[[]],\
[[1,1,12]],\
[[0,0,0],[30000,40,3010],[32000,40500,7520],[0,0,10520]],\
[[15340,0,0],[104300,0,3630], [434000,4434000,63460],[400340, 404300, 9430],[10340,0,1334320]]]



MaxLengthPerTrace=[[]]

traceCount = len(nList)
prevX = 0
prevY = 0
prevT = 0
maxLengthTempList=0

def calculateLength(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return math.sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2)
def calculateTime (t1,t2):
    return abs(t1-t2)

#Entry point
def getLengths():
    for traceIndex in range(0, len(nList)):
        print 'trace: ' + str(traceIndex+1)

        trace = nList[traceIndex]
        def getLenthsForElement():
            for pointIndex in range(0, len(trace)):
                point = trace[pointIndex]

                if len(point)>0:
                    tempX = point[0]
                    tempY = point[1]
                    tempT = point[2]

                    if pointIndex != 0:

                        #Calulate Length here
                        length = calculateLength(tempX, tempY, prevX, prevY)
                        yield length
        yield [l for l in getLenthsForElement()]                

#print the list of lists of weights
print [l for l in getLengths()]
#flatten all lists and get maximum.
lens = []
[lens.extend(l) for l in getLengths()]
print max(lens)
```

Comment: `[lens.extend(l) for l in getLengths()]` - using a list comprehension for side effects is a really bad practice - either use a normal `for` loop, or better yet, use `itertools.chain.from_iterable()` to flatten here.

Comment: You're completely right. I was not sure that  `lens =  [i for l in getLengths() for i in l]` is clear for beginner and implement fast and dirty approach. It's anyway have side effects in getLentgh() so i would leave my answer as it is.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that approach for flattening either. `itertools.chain.from_iterable(getLengths())` is the best way to flatten your iterable one level. It will be faster than any method relying on pure-python loops. In a similar vein, using `list(getLengthsForElement())` would be better than a no-op list comprehension if you feel you need a list.

Answer (score 1):

Make a list of the lengths, then get the maximum:

```
lengths = []
for point in trace:
    lengths.append(calculateLength(point[0], point[1], prevX, prevY));

maxLength = max(lengths)
print maxLength
```